How do sharing links work in mobile applications?
In a mobile application, I want to create sharing urls from within the application (for example, sharing the user profile), and when different clients click on this link, I want to redirect them to the app if the app is installed, if not to the store. I want to create and redirect this url with Nodejs (nestjs). What should the structure be like here?


Create the Shareable URL
First, you need to create a unique URL that can be shared. This URL will be processed by your server to determine the appropriate redirection.

Setup Universal Links and App Links
For iOS (Universal Links):


You need to host an apple-app-site-association file on your web server. This file informs iOS about the app that should handle the URLs.
For Android (App Links):
You need to host a assetlinks.json file on your web server to inform Android about the app that should handle the URLs.
3. Handling Redirections with Node.js (NestJS)
You will create an endpoint in your NestJS application that processes the incoming requests and redirects users based on their platform and whether they have the app installed.

As far as I understand, I will process the incoming requests according to the device type and make a redirect. 'You must host an apple-app-site-association file on your web server.' and 'you must host an assetlinks.json file on your web server.' . Can you give more detailed information about these parts? Or, if possible, can you provide a sample document or piece of code?
